# can not find params from route in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i have this senario :

when use register in site i send a email to that email . in that have a link and must click on that link for verify registertion .

that route have this information :

```
http://localhost:4200/auth/verify-checking?email={0}&code={1}
```

and i create this route :

```
  { path: 'verify-checking', component: CheckingVerifedComponent },
```

but i have tow problem :

A : can not find the params :

i use this code but not worked :

```
this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
  this.sendModel.email = params['email'];
  this.sendModel.code = params['code'];
});
```

B : it show me this error :

> Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'auth/verify-checking%3Femail%3Dkianoushvv123456@gmail.com&code%3DCfDJ8PQkunuAtiZOulV9qQ%252F3astuT%252Fa2VVXDAhxbE%252Fpg%252FfmcpXTcFXPR3gunRzs443wcxrxxWefG3PHVqmdbJL5GZX8dwgI0UuZTVDW%25206U2hSNBTQ1X7xT3YHh%2520%2520ym3%252FP3rlinriN4vgxJEMbmqPKQYe7XsnjcjYCtNvHY141nk%252FEYkoj6FZkEPuVdZO5qH%2520jNyRXA%253D%253D'

**how can i solve this problems ?????**

Comment: you should add pathMatch: 'full', like { path: 'verify-checking', component: CheckingVerifedComponent, pathMatch: 'full'}

Comment: @pbachman still show me that error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
http://localhost:4200/auth/verify-checking?email={0}&code={1}
```

queryParam is used for ?email={0}&code={1}

```
this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
  this.sendModel.email = params['email'];
  this.sendModel.code = params['code'];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may consider this:

Route

```
 { path: 'verify-checking/:email/:code', component: CheckingVerifedComponent }
```

Extracting the Parameters

```
this.sendModel.email = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('email');
this.sendModel.code = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('code');
```