# Don't go into the subscribe when server send a reponse in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to send a request to the server and check server response, but when I need to get a server response it does not show me any things.

I send a request in this code :

```js
SendVerifyInformation(item: SendVerificationModel): Observable < any > {
  return this.httpClient.post < any > (this.appConfig.apiEndpoint + '/Account/VerifyAccount', item);
}
```

and in component I write this code for process the server response :

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.SendData(this.sendModel);
}


SendData(sendModel): void {
    console.log('in')
    this.authService.SendVerifyInformation(sendModel).subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data)
        if (data['success']) {
            this.router.navigate(['/verified-success'])
        } else {
            console.log('in else ')
            this.router.navigate(['/invalid-token'])
        }
    })
}
```

what's the problem ? how can I solve this problem ???

Comment: Have you check the network tab in browser?

Comment: @huanfeng yes . server send the response but it not show me in console

Comment: What's the response of the server? The status code?

Comment: @Kokogino it show 200

Comment: And what is the response body of the response? What is console.log(data) supposed to print?

Comment: @Kokogino this is my problem . it not into the subscribe and not show me any things in conosle.log(data)

Comment: Yes, I undestand, but what SHOULD be printed?

Comment: @Kokogino yes .

Comment: @Kokogino and when i enter the page it show me this error : `core.js:6185 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'auth/verify-checking%3Femail%3Dkianoush12399456@gmail.com&code%3DCfDJ8PQkunuAtiZOulV9qQ%252F3ass7jyXiEWsOBWiiWFrN2ufErzmW5lOX9jQ9DeC2OJLuVMpq%2520ndzNnElXO%2520nsp2sn%2520bOhzXaT3DC6BPbJe1nz1H3lr5cOawj2gEdkgHz1lf4EX2Z68vx31P9WpMJ8OZT5GUVe1qLqxtGKkA%252F7V%2520PPj6uY96s1ZOHYXKlhXGZ1QThHg%253D%253D'`

Comment: @Kokogino you can see this question . maybe help for solve this problem : 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62676494/can-not-find-params-from-route-in-angular

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217068/discussion-between-kokogino-and-kianoush-dortaj).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you implement OnInit in your component. Otherwise ngOnInit and SendData methods won't get called.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './test.component.css' ]
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {}
```